# OpenCV Java error in linking library

Tags: java, opencv

I know this question is asked many times but I have tried all solutions.
I am using OpenCV in my Java project. In main function:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

public static void main(String[] argv){

    System.loadLibrary("lib"+Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(0);
    ...
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture.VideoCapture_2(I)J
    at org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture.VideoCapture_2(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture.<init>(VideoCapture.java:154)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Java Result: 1
```

Before anyone says this, I had to add `"lib"` before `Core.NATIVE...` so to load `libopencv_java300.dll`.

I am on `64 bit Windows 8` with `32 bit JDK 8`. I have build static version of OpenCV 3 from git source with `MinGW 4.8.0`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try: `static{ System.loadLibrary("lib"+Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);}` instead in `main`

Comment: Are you sure `System.loadLibrary("lib"+Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` works without any exception? If yes then you are not doing anything wrong, compiled dll is not correct.

Comment: @guneykayim, yes it appears that the dlls have some problem. I will now try to compile them myself

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, add this line

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

This should load all OpenCV libraries from the DLL (or .so or .dylib, depending on your OS)